# R3F: Div is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend?

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

[Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxpoQ.png)

I have been trying to add a ScrollControler and Scroll area to my app. I just keep running into the same issue.

| R3F: Div is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend?

I tried extending it, adding the Html import from react-three/drei, I also tried moving my  from , but still running into the same issue.

```
import './App.css';
import { extend } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { ScrollControls, Scroll } from '@react-three/drei'
import { Html } from '@react-three/drei';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
extend({ ScrollControls, })

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <color attach="background" args={['#000000']} />

      <ScrollControls pages={6} damping={0.25}>
        <Scroll>

        </Scroll>
        <Scroll>
          <Container style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
            <Row className='text-center align-items-center justify-content-center' style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100vw', height: '100vh', padding: '0px 30px 0px' }}>
              <Col xs={6}>
                <Html>
                  <div>
                    <h1 style={{ marginBottom: '0px' }}>Life can be a struggle</h1>
                  </div>
                </Html>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </Scroll>
      </ScrollControls >
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```